# get result from select statement put into header

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have problem: 
- I have select statement

```
Select name from org where id = 123
```

I can get value from statement that puting into header
ex: result is "aread" then header column is "aread"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:

[Oracle - dynamic column name in select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860516/oracle-dynamic-column-name-in-select-statement)

Comment: This is not an Answer. If you want to mark as possible duplicate, use the CLOSE link. If you are too new to the forum and don't privileges to do that (I don't remember if that is the case), using an Answer instead is not appropriate anyway. Please voluntarily DELETE your "answer".

Comment: I don't see a close link. Linking OP to a possible answer is more helpful to OP than rigid conformity to protocol.